# Unexpected error message (Undefined control sequence. l.18 \xwm@secstopagerange)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, miktex, compilation-error

The following basic TikZ code is throwing the compilation error via PDFLaTeX:

```
("C:\fakepath\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/generic/pgf/frontendla yer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex"))) (Test.aux !
Undefined control sequence. l.18 \xwm@secstopagerange
                         {{10000}{19}} ?
```

Here's an MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (10,0);

  \draw (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

After updating packages in MikTeX, I get the following error:

```
("C:\fakepath\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/frontendla
yer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex"))) (Test.aux
! Undefined control sequence.
l.18 \xwm@secstopagerange
                         {{10000}{19}}
?
```

I am not sure why. Please explain the reason for the error.

Comment: Off-topic: Congrats on passing the 5k rep mark!!

Comment: When did you most recently update your MikTeX distribution? I don't have MikTeX; on MacTeX2019, your code compiles without fuss.

Comment: @Mico thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only reproduce the issue if I load the `xwatermark` package, compile the document and then recompile after removing the package.

Just remove the `.aux` file or go past the error. In the next LaTeX run there will be no problem.